# R: change data frame structure using values from one variable as new variable

Tags: r, list, data-structures, dataframe, dplyr

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    name = c("a", "b", "b", "c"),
    score = c(1, 1, 2, 1)
    )
```

How can I get a new data frame with variables/columns from df$name and with each 'corresponding' `df$score`. I figure that its actually a two-step problem:

First I would need to make a list of (in this example) unequal length vectors like this:

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 1 2

$c
[1] 1
```

Second, NAs need to be padded so one get vectors of equal length before making the desired data frame
that would be like:

```
   a b  c
1  1 1  1
2 NA 2 NA
```

I cannot find any simple means to do this - Im sure there must be! 
If the solution can be delivered using dplyr it would be fantastic! Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a fairly straight-forward reshape from long to wide case. Have a look at the gazillinon of posts on this topic on SO. Search for e.g. `reshape2` and `dcast`; `tidyr` and `spread`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To split the data:

```
(s <- split(df1$score, df1$name))
# $a
# [1] 1
#
# $b
# [1] 1 2
#
# $c
# [1] 1
```

To create the new data frame:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(s, `length<-`, max(vapply(s, length, 1L))))
#    a b  c
# 1  1 1  1
# 2 NA 2 NA
```

Slightly more efficient would be to use `vapply` in place of `sapply`

```
len <- max(vapply(s, length, 1L))
as.data.frame(vapply(s, `length<-`, double(len), len))
#    a b  c
# 1  1 1  1
# 2 NA 2 NA
```

Comment: Oh, yes.  They sure are.  That's even better :)

Comment: Whats the 'length<-' doing ?

Comment: @user3375672 - `\`length<-\`` is extending the length of each vector in the list to the length of the list's longest vector, padding each with NA. `max(vapply(s, length, 1L))` is the length we're extending them to

Comment: Thats really smart - sure could use that in other circumstances!

Comment: @user3375672 - Absolutely.  Just a note: `\`length<-\`(x, 5)` is the same as doing `length(x) <- 5` but the result is not returned invisibly

Comment: @RichardScriven I have learned this type of data cleaning on SO. But, `length<-` is even better!  +1 :) (By the way, you could use Giants pic till next World Series if you want! Celebrate till 2015!)

Comment: @jazzurro - It might be time to put up a 49ers one now.